# Programmatically get a color from an Asset Catalog in 10.11?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan

You can add a color set to an .xcassets file, and you can reference that color in other .xibs, and all of that works in 10.11.

But [NSColor colorNamed:] is 10.13+.

How can one programmatically get an NSColor by name from an .xcassets file in 10.11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to get NSColor under 10.12 or earlier. You need to hard-code them somewhere as a fallback for earlier versions.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the case.  I wrote a script to extract the universal entries from the asset registry and create code to return either the namedColor (10.14+) or the fixed universal code (10.13-).  It's not entirely ideal, but better than trying to keep them in sync by hand.